# Why is my script not showing input characters dynamically in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a TextField in which when I give any input it show on div and this script is showing inputs but not properly...
I don't know where I am making mistakes and I request that please give your answers only in JavaScript please don't use jquery. Thank you .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
<input name="t" value="" onkeypress="printvalues();">
</form>
<div id="divId"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

script

```
function printvalues() {
    var div = document.getElementById("divId");
    div.innerHTML += form.t.value;
}
```

[Here is my code with output](http://jsbin.com/eqilur/1/edit)

Comment: "but not properly" --- define what is "properly". Also - do you realize what `+=` does?

Comment: `div.innerHTML = form.t.value` should do.

Comment: @elclanrs, yes, and I would add that using `onkeyup` in this case is better than `onkeypress`.

Comment: @zerkms i got it i was adding two strings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function printvalues() {
    var div = document.getElementById("divId");
    div.innerHTML = document.form.t.value;
}
```

**EDIT**:The keypress event executes before the value of textbox is changed so use keyup() event which triggers when the key is released instead like

```
<input name="t" value="" onkeyup="printvalues();">
```

Comment: As I can see, with this test "aba", the last letter is missing, so I don't know how this solution helped you..

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is here....

Just change **onkeypress** to **onkeyup**

Made below changes and enjoy..

```
 function printvalues(a) {
 var div = document.getElementById("divId");
 div.innerHTML=a;
}

<input type="text" name="t"  onkeyup="printvalues(this.value);">
```